# Rails 4: Model union with itself

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model

I'm a rails newbie so forgive. 
I have a existing DB schema

```
create_table "registrations", force: true do |t|
   t.string   "name",                                   null: false
   t.string   "product1",                               null: false
   t.string   "product_serial1",                        null: false
   t.string   "product2",                               null: false
   t.string   "product_serial2",                        null: false
   t.string   "product3",                               null: false
   t.string   "product_serial3",                        null: false
   t.string   "product4",                               null: false
   t.string   "product_serial4",                        null: false
end
```

On the UI i want to be able to search for a serial number and it needs to search product1, product2, product3...

My thinking is to have the model union with itself so all the products are returned in their own row like

```
select name, product1 product, serial1 serial from registrations where product1 != ''
union all
select name, product2 product, serial2 serial from registrations where product2 != ''
union all
select name, product3 product, serial3 serial from registrations where product3 != ''
union all
select name, product4 product, serial4 serial from registrations where product4 != ''
```

Can Rails do something like this in the model? Like from the controller, if I registrations.search(), it'll return the above SQL by default.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is something like the following

```
Registration.where("product_serial1 = ? OR product_serial2 = ? OR product_serial3 = ? OR product_serial4 = ?", search_string, search_string, search_string, search_string)
```

As a side note, you may really want to take another look at your schema.  Those product serial numbers look like they belong in a products table and your registration table should join to many products through an intermediate table.  This [article](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) may be of some help.

Comment: That is what I currently have but looking for a better solution. The problem with the above is if a user has two products and one of the serial matches, in the view I display both product1 and product2 because that is what the result set is. Ideally I would only return the one result that matches the one product.

I am thinking that maybe I need to adjust the DB. Am hoping not to since this is an existing DB.

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```
Registration.where("product_serial1 like :search or product_serial2 like :search or product_serial3 like :search or product_serial4 like :search", search: "#{params[:search]}")
```

This will search all of the serial fields and only return matching records. Note the this example uses `params[:search]` but this can just be replaced with a variable.